# Node.js error: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use

Tags: javascript, node.js

**For testing purposes, I've set up this little script:**

```
Client = require('mysql').Client, client = new Client(); 
client.user = 'root'; client.password = 'root'; client.port = 8889;

counter = 0; data = '';
setInterval(update, 10);

function update(){
    counter++; request();
}
var sys = require('sys'), fs = require('fs'), http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),port = 8001;

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    }); response.end('Hello world');
}).listen(port);

function request(){
    client.connect();
    client.query('USE db');
    client.query(
    'SELECT * FROM table', function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        if(results.length > 0)
        {
            var firstResult = results[0];
            data = firstResult['data'];
        }
        client.end();
    }
    );
}
```

**It works fine, but, after an hour or so, the server crashes and outputs the following error:**

```
node.js:180
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use
```

---

**UPDATE**

I updated the code. It now includes some mysql. **This definitely is causing the problem, although I don't know exactly why.** Leaving this part out stabilizes the loop. Also, I updated the time interval to every 10 ms. (The server crashes after a few minutes with the mysql part in it, but keeps on running without)

Comment: What about listening on another port?

Comment: @pimvdb - Would that make a difference?

Comment: Personally, I've used random ports like `15382` without that error so far, so it might be worth a try.

Comment: I'm trying it as we speak, but out of curiosity, how would that make a difference?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure; does it suddenly crash after an hour stating that the address is in use already? Logically thinking, a new application would get that error since your server is using that port.

Comment: It indeed suddenly crashes with the error described. Still don't know how that can happen though. The server has been running for about 15 minutes now, listening on a different port.

Comment: That's a pity. Let me try running your server in the background... It will take some time though I guess :o)

Comment: No problem at all. Thanks! I hope you'll find something.

Comment: `Error: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use` means someone else is listening on port 8001. More information is needed

Comment: How can that be? It's on my localhost, and I have no ports forwarded, so the outside world cannot connect to my ip. Can it be a timeout/blocking problem?

Comment: Still running, counter is at 3459 currently.

Comment: @Kriem: I do get the error if I try to run a second instance of the server, but the original one keeps running smoothly...

Comment: That's odd. Now I'm clueless again. Thanks for the effort anyway! :)

Comment: Hmm, looking at the code again, I see I still have a function inside the update loop that calls a mysql db request. See the update in the question.

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to try connecting once and execute a query each 10ms without disconnecting. Connecting 100 times a second doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @pimvdb - That's exactly what the problem was! I came here to answer my question to see you've already found the solution. Thanks a lot! Perhaps you could make it a real answer below so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting every 10ms, which puts a heavy load on your MySQL server. I do not know how it's possible that you get a 'address in use' error, but you might want to try connecting once and use the connection to execute queries.

Just like you don't log out and log back in again and again at a messenger application for each message you want to send to someone :)

Comment: I actually believe this alone might not fix the problem. Watch your node process and your sql server process closely. I predict either of them or both will keep growing in memory usage until either of them crashes.

Answer (score 3):

You really should honor pimvb's comment about not connecting 100 times a second to the database. If node-mysql doesn't clean up the connections correctly or immediately this will most likely have you run out of available ports for connections within about an hour (actually more like 10 minutes or so, use `netstat | grep WAIT | wc -l` to see how many closed connections you have pending).

Also, you should be aware of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript/node.js. You might not want to run new queries in such a tight loop while other queries are still pending. This will only pile up and the SQL server will choke.

**UPDATE**

Something like the following should prevent you from choking your server. It will issue as many request as possible but no more than 1 every 10 ms. *Disclaimer: hacked in so textbox, not tested!*

```
Client = require('mysql').Client, client = new Client(); 
client.user = 'root'; client.password = 'root'; client.port = 8889;

counter = 0; data = '';

client.connect(function {
    setInterval(update, 10);

    var queryPending = false, queryReIssue = false;

    function update(){
        if (queryPending) {
            queryReIssue = true;
        } else {
            request();
        }
        counter++;
    }
    var sys = require('sys'), fs = require('fs'), http = require('http'),
        url = require('url'),port = 8001;

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        }); response.end('Hello world');
    }).listen(port);

    function request(){
        requestPending = true;
        client.query('USE db');
        client.query('SELECT * FROM table', function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
            requestPending = false;
            if (err) { console.log('ERROR: ' + err.message) }
            if(results.length > 0) {
                var firstResult = results[0];
                data = firstResult['data'];
            }
            if (queryReIssue) {
                queryReIssue = false;
                request();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right about the pile of queries. I'm trying out some node  stuff and this was just an experiment.

Comment: It's not just because they are alot, but due to the nature of node.js and asynchronous IO it is possible (and actually very likely if there's a large dataset in your table), that you will issue the next query *before* the previous query finished. That is propably the case here, this would also explain, why you run out of available ports: after an hour ~65000 queries (and with them 65000 open connections) piled up, because you query and connect more often than the SQL server can handle.

Comment: TL;DR: do not query your sql server again before the previous query's callback was called and do not connect back to the sql server before the end()'s callback (wich you don't even use) was fired.

Comment: How would I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for the insights! This will definitely help with understanding Node. Powerful stuff.